# runtime error, but debugging step by step works fine

Tags: android, camera, runtime-error

I wrote an android program to take a picture without preview. My programs works fine when I debug it step by step. However, when I run it in execution mode, the program doesn't work as expected. No picture is saved and the program can not finish. In addition, I can not use my camera in other android applications(e.g. Camera, Camcorder) unless I restart my phone. Anybody have any ideas about this problem? The code for taking pictures and the logged errors is as follows:

Code for taking pictures:

```
    SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mCamera.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

The callback function

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
          public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
               if (imageData != null) {
            StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,
                    "ImageName");
            finish();
        }
    }
};
}
```

The reported errors by logcat:

```
ERROR/Adreno200-ES20(130): rb verson is SBA #24
ERROR/mm-camera(130): prepare snapshot: Aec not settle
ERROR/CameraService(130): mHardware->setOverlay() failed with status -2147483648
ERROR/mm-camera(130): camera_issue_command: get_picture error (Connection timed out): length 36, status 0 FD: 20 1
ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware3D(130): getPicture: CAMERA_OPS_GET_PICTURE ioctl failed!
ERROR/NotificationService(292): adbEnabled = false
ERROR/NotificationService(292): adbEnabled = true
```

Can anybody give any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    currentTimeString + ".jpg");
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. No pictures is taken and saved on sd card. And also the preview mode of camera is started.

Comment: ya i wasnt sure when i posted if this did show a preview, i guess so.  i know this code works for taking a picture though(tested and working implementations on phone and emulator)  so maybe there is something else going on for you.  are you using an emulator or an actual device?